# How do I draw a diagonal line of one character using nested while loops in Python code?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, character

I need to write a program that will output a diagonal line using nested while loops.

It should look like this:

```
*
 *
  *
   *
    *
```

I know how to draw a square:

```
    row = 1
    while row <= size:
        col = 1
        while col <= size:
            print chr,
            col = col + 1

        print ''

        row = row + 1
    print ''
```

which outputs:

```
    * * * * *
    * * * * *
    * * * * *
    * * * * *
    * * * * *
```

but I cant seem to wrap my head around the diagonal line.
If someone could help it would be greatly appreciated.
The code has to use while loops though.

Comment: Only print if `row` and `col` are equal.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually pretty close:

```
size = 4
row = 1
while row <= size:
    col = 1
    while col < row:
        print ' ',
        col = col + 1

    print '*'

    row = row + 1  # simplify to `row += 1`
```

The trick here is that in the inner loop, you print **spaces** (not the character) until you've printed 1 less space than the row number that you're on.  Then you break out of the loop, print your character and newline and then continue.

Comment: We wrote exactly the same solution. I will delete mine now.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I didn't realize that.

Answer (score 0):

In method, just pass it how long you want the line to be:

```
def diagonalLine( size ):

 row = 1
    while row <= size:
        col = 1
        while col <= size:
            print ' ',
            col += 1

        print '*'
```